# Putting two rows together on the same row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's take as example this table, which associate a product to the number 
of stars he received from customer's feedbacks (it happens to be ordered by number of stars):

```
| ProductID |  Stars  | 
|-----------|---------|
|    23     |    10   |
|    12     |    10   |
|    17     |     9   |
|     5     |     8   |
|    20     |     8   |
|    18     |     7   |
```

How would I select (showing them on the same row) the IDs of the products
in pairs?

Like this:

```
|  Product1 |   Product2  | 
|-----------|-------------|
|    23     |      12     |
|    17     |       5     |
|    20     |      18     |
```

Or like this:

```
|     Products     | 
|------------------|
|    23     12     |
|    17      5     |
|    20     18     |
```

Comment: Don't use the database engine to provide you with a certain formatting; that belongs to the domain of an application *connecting* to it, and then rendering the information in a nice format.

Comment: How are you pairing them up - simply ordering (by stars desc, id desc?) and alternating them? And why does the title say 'two or more'? You need to know how many columns you'll generate, or would have to do it dynamically. As trincot said this sounds like something your application should probably be doing for display.

Comment: In this case I'm ordering them by stars desc.The title says two or more rows because I can imagine the same technique could be used to do the job for more than just one row. Maybe the title is a bit confusing, I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

Use listagg to produce option2

```
select stars, listagg(ProductID, ' ') within group (order by ProductID) as Products
from Table1
group by Stars
```

Comment: The OP's requirement is clearly not grouping by `Stars`.

Answer (score 0):

On oracle you can use a function call listagg which works sort of like join in C# (and other languages.)  For it to work you need to have something to group buy -- it seems you want to group by every other when ordered by a column.  First make a row number for the column and then group by that div 2

so

```
SELECT LISTAGG(ProductID, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ProductID) AS ProductList
FROM (
  SELECT ProductID, FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Stars)+1)/2) as GroupByMe FROM Table
) X
GROUP BY GroupByMe
```

If you want to do every 3, just /3 instead.

More interesting (because more people want to see it) is getting a list for every amount of stars, that looks like this:

```
SELECT Stars as StarCount, LISTAGG(ProductID, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ProductID) As ProductList
FROM Table
GROUP BY Stars
```

of course this looks like a prior answer because this is what people would expect you would want.

Comment: You should use `ceil()` rather than `floor()` - with `floor()` you only get n-1 values in the first listagg and then n at a time. Much worse, though, - are you ordering-within-group and grouping by the same expression in the outer query? SQL 101.

Comment: ah good point about floor, I added 1.  Not sure I would call the other typo sql 101 :D

Comment: I don't see a typo. I see within group order by GroupByMe but you group by the same expression. So GroupByMe is CONSTANT in each group. Unless one of them was a "typo" :-)

Comment: I am sure you know the proper meaning - a rookie makes that mistake, I think they don't know better; an experienced player makes that mistake, I think they rush an answer out without giving it too much thought. Which I think does no good to the community. I do my best to call out such instances; there are, actually, a lot of rookies who get confused exactly by that kind of mistake, and then "they remember with 100% certainty they saw a very experienced person write it that way." Sorry if I came across as mean, didn't mean to - but I did want to make this point, as nicely as I knew how.

Comment: Same to you! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why in your output you picked 5 before 20; remember that rows in a table are NOT ORDERED. In my solution I order by stars and then by productid; if your rows are ordered by something else as well, you may use that instead.

You may change 2 to 7 in the divisions by 2 if you want to group 7 values at a time.

This is offered only to show that this CAN be done in Oracle SQL (in the database). It SHOULDN'T, but that's for you to decide.

```
with
     inputs ( productid, stars) as ( 
       select 23, 10 from dual union all
       select 12, 10 from dual union all
       select 17,  9 from dual union all
       select  5,  8 from dual union all
       select 20,  8 from dual union all
       select 18,  7 from dual
     )
-- end of test data, solution begins below
select listagg(productid, ' ') within group (order by rn) as result
from ( select productid, stars,
              row_number() over (order by stars desc, productid desc) as rn
       from   inputs
     )
group by ceil(rn/2)
order by ceil(rn/2)
;

RESULT
------
23 12
17 20
5 18
```

Comment: I see a downvote but no explanation. Is there something wrong with the answer? If you don't leave a note, how will we know?

Comment: this sure looks correct to me why the downvote? I gave it an upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT 23 product_id, 10 stars FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 12, 10 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 17, 9 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 20, 8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 18, 7 FROM DUAL),
     t2
     AS (  SELECT product_id,
                  stars,
                    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY stars DESC)
                  + MOD (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY stars DESC), 2)
                     grp
             FROM t
         ORDER BY stars DESC)
  SELECT LISTAGG (product_id, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY stars DESC, ROWNUM)
            AS product_id
    FROM t2
GROUP BY grp
```

result

```
23 12
17 5
20 18
```